# Numbering of subsubsections: "A." in number, "1.1.1.A" in references

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, numbering

I'm quite new to Latex and I'd like to achieve the following thing.

I want my document to have the following numbering structure:

```
1. chapter 
1.1 section
1.1.1 subsection 
A. subsubsection.
```

(In the TOC I only want the chapters, sections and subsections to be listed.)

I achieved this by adding the following extra lines in the beginning of my LaTex document:

```
% set section numbering depth
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % 3 => section, subsection, subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % 2 => section, subsection
% replace subsubsection numbering by single letter
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}
```

Problem: when I make a reference to this subsubsection, I get something like this:

```
A
```

I want this to be formatted like this:

```
1.1.1.A
```

Comment: Maybe you will do like this: `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\Alph{subsubsection}}
\def\subsubsection#1{\par\vskip10pt\noindent\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\textbf{\Alph{subsubsection}\quad #1}\par\noindent}` ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I removed 'thanks' from your post since we omit this. Instead, you should [up-vote and accept the answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask), giving the answerer the site reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Without using additioal packages, you can simply redefine `\p@subsubsection` which controls the prefix used for cross-referencing subsubsection:

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Alph{subsubsection}} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subsubsection{\thesubsection.} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
A cross-reference to some subsubsections: \ref{a}, \ref{b} and \ref{c}.
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}\label{a}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}\label{b}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}\label{c}

\end{document}
```

Am image of the obtained ToC:

[image]

And an image of the document body, showing the desired formatting for the headings and the cross-references:

[image]

On a side (personal) note, as **tohecz** has already mentioned, I think this might be confusing since it introduces some level of inconsistency (the string used for the cross-references doesn't really belong to the object that is being referenced).

Answer (score 2):

Using `titlesec` package, you can control what gets displayed as the subsection number, and it can be different from `\thesubsection`. The example is on `article` (without chapters), but that makes no difference.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\Alph{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\Alph{subsubsection}}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{SSSSS}
\subsection{TTTTT}
\subsection{TTTTT II}
\subsubsection{UUUUU}
\subsubsection{UUUUU II}
\subsection{TTTTT III}
\subsubsection{UUUUU III}

\end{document}
```

However, I do not consider it a good style, it is a bit confusing IMO, but it depends on how you use it.