# Section/Subsection, cited including the subsection with a dot and auto include supra/infra

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

So here is my next issue, this time in the cross-reference. I've tried some [other posts found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91549/numbering-of-subsubsections-a-in-number-1-1-1-a-in-references?rq=1) to use the reference with a mixture of formatting related to my requirements and TOC formatting. I'd like the following :

- My section are "I.", "II."
- My subsection are : "1.", "2.", without repeating the section
- All my TOC entries are cited with the trailing "."
- All the subsection cite should include the section but without the trailing dot, i.e. "II.1", "I.2".
- All the section cite should be just the section the trailing dot, i.e. "I" or "II"
- Finally, I'd love to have the automated inclusion of "supra" and "infra" keyword.

To explain on the supra/infra, the is a mandatory requirement (language/domain constraint) that indicate the relative position of the "infra" if the cited part will appears below and supra if the cited part has already been seen above the citation.

I guess all the formatting should be "easy" even if my example is currently not working fine with all the "dots" part.

And additionally, is there a way to make a special command that include the "supra/infra" directly ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test Section 1}
A cross-reference to some Subsection that comes below: \ref{a}, \ref{b} and \ref{c}.
This would ideally be cited "infra \ref{a}" and "infra \ref{b}"

\subsection{Test Subsection}\label{a}

\section{Test Section 2}
\subsection{Test Subsubsection}\label{b}
At this point \ref{a} is above citation and \ref{c} is below. It should cite "supra \ref{a}" and "infra \ref{c}"

\section{Test Section 3}
\subsection{Test Subsubsection}\label{c}

A cross-reference to some Subsection that comes below: \ref{a}, \ref{b} and \ref{c}.
This would ideally be cited supra \ref{a}, supra \ref{b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the KOMA document classes (`scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need the table of contents to agree and the "infra"/"supra" thing.

You can use `tocloft` for the TOC and a solution similar to [Reference "up" or "down"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360840/35864) for "supra"/"infra". The trick is that we can just check if the label was already created, if yes, we have a "supra" reference, if no it must be "infra" (that assumes that all references are defined, undefined references are "infra", but that should be OK).

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}% default is 1.5em
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{1.5em}% default is 2.3em
\def\cftsecaftersnum{.}
\def\cftsubsecaftersnum{.}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\xawi@seenlabels}{}
\newcommand*{\lawlabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \label{#1}%
  \listadd{\xawi@seenlabels}{#1}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand*{\lawref@supinf}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\xawi@seenlabels}
    {supra}
    {infra}}
\newcommand*{\lawref}[1]{%
  \lawref@supinf{#1}~\ref{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Test Section 1}\lawlabel{d}
A cross-reference to some Subsection that comes below: \lawref{a}, \lawref{b} and \lawref{c}.
This would ideally be cited "infra \ref{a}" and "infra \ref{b}"

\subsection{Test Subsection}\lawlabel{a}

\section{Test Section 2}
\subsection{Test Subsubsection}\lawlabel{b}
At this point \lawref{a} is above citation and \lawref{c} is below. It should cite "supra \ref{a}" and "infra \ref{c}" finally \lawref{d}

\section{Test Section 3}
\subsection{Test Subsubsection}\lawlabel{c}

A cross-reference to some Subsection that comes below: \lawref{a}, \lawref{b} and \lawref{c}.
This would ideally be cited supra \ref{a}, supra \ref{b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for the solution. This works fine, but I noted that every `lawref` which are cited before the first `lawlabel` will trigger an error : "<argument> \xawi@seenlabels                             
l.42 \lawref{a}               
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed"

I'm only assuming that the lawref is tryting to grab a list who is not defined at all yet, hence triggering the error. I'll not have a text using the ref before the label, so not an issue in my case, but this is something to consider, I'd say

Comment: @XaWi Yes that was stupid. Fixed in the edit.

Comment: @XaWi And? Does it work as expected now?

Comment: Hey Moewe, sorry, it worked fine! That's great and I validated it. The etoolbox package looks like a great one, I should have a deeper look at it!